# How to find/mount my hard drive on dedicated server?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

**SOLUTION**: CentOS can not install on drives larger than 2TB; downgraded drive to 2 TB.

I recently rented a dedicated server and bought a large hard disk size upgrade (3TB).

But, linux reports I have very little space, here is the results of "df -h"

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda3              69G  6.1G   60G  10% /

/dev/sda1             487M   23M  439M   5% /boot

tmpfs                 989M     0  989M   0% /dev/shm
```

My questions:

1. Do I need to find and mount the hard drive, if so, how?
2. Or, did the server provider make a mistake?

**Edit:** Here is the output of "fdisk -l", as requested:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9726 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      514048+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2              65         574     4096575   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3             575        9725    73505407+  83  Linux
```

**Edit2:** Here is the invoice I paid showing I should have a 3TB drive:

```
Invoice Items

AMD Athlon II X2 260 (07/11/2013 - 08/10/2013)
CPU: AMD Athlon Dual-Core 260 3.2GHz: Included
Operating System: CentOS 5.x 64-bit (Recommended): Included
Control Panel: None
RAM: 2GB DDR2 RAM: Included
Primary Hard Drive: 3TB HDD SATA2: recurring /* HERE */
Secondary Hard Drive: None
RAID Configuration (Multiple HDDs only): None
Bandwidth: 5TB: Included (Overages billed $.05 per GB)
Port: 100Mbps: Included
Additional IP Addresses: Plan Default
Managed Server: Self-Managed
Managed Firewall: Self-Managed Software Firewall
Managed Backup: None
Microsoft SQL Server (Windows OS only): None
```

**Edit3:** I am filing a support request with my server provider. Thank you everyone who tried to help!

Comment: Did they add a drive or replace a drive?  The output you're showing only shows a single hard drive, with partitions 1 and 3 mounted, which was probably you're existing drive.  I'm going to guess that you now have another drive, likely at `/dev/sdb` that will need to be formatted and mounted.  Note that since you have a dedicated server, that management usually falls upon you . . .

Comment: Yep, that's showing an 80GB drive . . . it's also not clear if the drive has hot added or not, if the system needs a reboot to see the drive, etc.  fdisk also won't work on GPT drives, which is what you'll need for a 3TB drive, so you should probably use `parted`

Comment: @ernie's first post: When I rented the server, I choose to upgrade my primary drive from 500GB to 3TB.

Comment: Are you sure it was a physical drive upgrade, and not a storage or transfer limit upgrade?  The 500GB or 3TB may be offered elsewhere . . . the output of `mount` or `df -h` may provide more info . . .

Comment: Yep, I have posted the invoice.

Comment: Looks like they screwed up and didn't give you the drive on your invoice . . .

Comment: How many physical HDD installed in your server?

Comment: Only one I think. I have posted the invoice I paid. The plan came with a 500GB hard drive, I upgraded that to a 3TB drive for a recurring fee.

Comment: Yep, they have not supplied the drive you paid for.  Also the fact that it is *exactly* 80 billion bytes makes me think this isn't a physical drive at all, but a virtual one.  Check what `hdparm -I /dev/sda` says.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

You will likely need to format the drive and create a filesystem on it, before mounting it into your current filesystem.

**Disclaimer**: I take no responsibility for any data loss herein.

Assuming your second drive shows up as `/dev/sdb` and you want to use the `ext4` filesystem and mount as `/mnt/bigdrive` (all commands being run as root):

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
n (create new partition)
p (primary partition)
1 (first partition)
t (change partition type)
83 (Linux partition type)
p (print the current partition table to verify)
w (write partition table to disk)

mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
mkdir -p /mnt/bigdrive
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/bigdrive
echo "/dev/sdb1 /mnt/bigdrive ext4 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Documentation on how to use `fdisk` is [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html). I suggest you read it before running any of the commands above - needless to say that one slip could lose you data!